# newly created user automatically logged in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, createuserwizard

I am using the create user wizard in asp.net from the admin privileges. i.e only admin can create a user.

I am creating a new user with a role assigned to it.

As soon as the user is created , it is automatically logged in with always 'admin' as the role (first in the option of dropdownlist of role) inspite of whatever other role i select.

I do not want the newly created user to be logged in automatically.

How to do it.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set [LoginCreatedUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.logincreateduser.aspx) to false to disable auto-login.

Comment: the above property when set to false worked. but still there is a problem. The dropdownlist which contains all roles always shows the admin value inspite of selecting any other role. I have used the `code` :

protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, ddl.SelectedItem.ToString());
 }

Comment: it is possible to assign multiple roles for user. try to debug CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser and check Roles.GetRolesForUser output before AddUserToRole call - maybe user is already added to administrators list. also check that ddl.SelectedItem returns correct value.

Comment: I tried it ..but it is always returning the first value of the dropdownlist i.e. admin and assigning every new user created the prvilge of admin. I have posted the question at the link below :

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263820/retain-value-of-roles-dropdownlist-in-create-userwizard-in-asp-net)